# undefined method `rfc822' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I was chugging along with fullcalendar in rails 3.2 on ruby 1.9.3-p320, made a few custom routes to my eventsController and then made these routes into fullcalendar eventSources

```
 #config/routes.rb
 match '/my_events', :to => 'events#my_events', :as => "my_events"
 
 #calendar.js
    {
        url: '/my_events',
        color: '#33FDC0',
        textColor: 'black',
        ignoreTimezone: true
    },

 #EventsController
 def my_events

   @events = current_user.events

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @events }
   end
 end
```

The events don't show up though (although they are creating I can get to them through /events/:id and in the console).

In the JS console in Chrome I'm getting this error:

```
    GET http://localhost:3000/my_events?start=1341118800&end=1341723600&_=1342200460434 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Which on the page itself looks like this:

## NoMethodError in EventsController#my_events

#### undefined method `rfc822' for nil:NilClass

Comment: have a look at your logs/development.log file and look at the stacktrace. you will find the line where this error happens. some value is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure this out, but I did fix it. I reset the database and it started working. I think some elements had no start dates and times making the whole socket konk out.